# how to prevent access denied exception

Tags: java

my program searches for files of a particular extension in my PC. but it can't search in `C:\Windows` folder. it is showing me

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Fax\Incoming error
```

Comment: Check if you're allowed to read a folder before you try and read the folder...

Comment: Try to run your program as administrator. Also have a look at "File.canRead()" method.

Comment: What is your question? Isn't it pretty obvious that it actually IS forbidden for a regular user to browse that directory?

Comment: Running the program with Administrator rights should work in this case.

Comment: Don't try to access files you don't have the right to. This is probably the best way to prevent those errors.

Comment: then how to hide access denied exception?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to search in that folder? If so you will have to run it with administrator elevated user or you can create a user with read only access to that folder and run the application with that user. I would ask myself twice if my program needs to read that folder...

Answer (score 0):

See what ever user account your program is running under and grant that account access. On the other hand, another approach could be to make your program run under some account which already has access rights.

If any `permission denied` obstacle could be programmatically sorted out without the need of any other form of credentials security would be pretty much useless.

Comment: It's important to say "Run as Administrator" in the programm settings in windows. The rights are ignoried, even if your logged in as root/administrator. Then you don't run the programm automaticaly as administrator (only if you turned off UAC)